# Dot Net Standard Enquiry

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I have some question about dot net standard which some terms I not understand.

1. The higher the version of .Net Standard, the more APIs are available to you.  What the meaning the API mention here?
2. The lower the version of .Net Standard, the more platforms implement it.  Whats the meaning of the platforms mention here

Comment: It means each newer version in .net standard equipped with new features that wasn't supported in previous releases, so any new library that targets higher versions in .net standard will be compatible with newer framework versions.

Please refer to the below compatibility diagram for different platforms.
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: Platforms are .net framework, .netcore, windows store, uwp, windows phone, silverlight, xbox360, hololens, etcetera.  Descriptive of the kind of device your program runs on, they have custom versions of the CLR host and can't implement all of the BCL types.  Several of these are dead, so it got easier to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

.Net Standard is, effectively, just a list of features; for example (and this is very unlikely to be one, but it illustrates the point), say a feature of .Net Standard was a File.Read function; so .Net Standard 1.0 might not have that, but .Net standard 2.0 might.  So, Windows 8.1 implements .Net Standard 1.0, but not .Net Standard 2.0; so by using v1.0 you support Windows, but you can't use that functionality, because it doesn't exist on that platform.

There are a list of supported platforms and versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft talks about .NET Standard they *generally** just mean the .NET Standard *specification*: a list of API's. The name API is kind of confusing here, so think of it as *features*. If a platform implements the .NET Standard, they must offer all those API's. With each subsequent version, extra API's/features will be added, so the higher the version of the standard, the more API's/features that are part of it.

*Platforms* are *implementations* of the .NET Standard. They consist of a runtime (for instance the CLR, CoreCLR, Mono or UWP), and a *Base Class Library*. The Base Class Library or BCL must contain all the API's/features listed in the standard.

Currently, Microsoft has four .NET Standard platforms: the .NET Framework (4.5 and up), .NET Core, UWP and Mono.

As you can see in the [list of implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), various versions of each platform support various versions of the Standard. Because they are all backwards compatible (each newer version is - barring some deprecation - essentially a superset of the previous version), the highest version of the standard a platform implements, the more API's or features it offers.

So if you target .NET Standard 2.0, you can see that there are eight platforms that support it: the latest versions of .NET Core, .NET Framework, Mono, various Xamarin platforms, UWP, and Unity.

However, if you target .NET Standard 1.0, there will be *twenty-one* platforms that support your application: .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.6, 4.6.1, Mono 4.6, Mono 4.6.1 etc. Remember, they're backwards compatible, so -all- platforms that implement a version of .NET Standard technically also implement version 1.0 of the .NET Standard. 
That's what they mean with "The lower the version, the more platforms implement it.

*I say generally because they sometimes also refer to the NetStandard.Library metapackage as .NET Standard, although that's technically not correct.

Comment: If backward compatible, why .Net Standard 1.0 .Net Framework 4.5.1?  In the list, .Net Framework 4.5.1 is support by .Net Standard 1.2 version.

Comment: If I choose .Net Standard 1.3, will it support Windows Phone 8.1 platform?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1 implements .NET Standard 1.2. Version 4.5 of the .NET Framework implements .NET Standard 1.1 (and, subsequently, 1.0 as well). I don't really understand what you mean by "why .NET Standard 1.0 .NET Framework 4.5.1?"

Comment: No, as you can see in the list, WP8.1 only supports up to .NET Standard 1.2. .NET Standard 1.3 defines API's that are not available on WP8.1, so targetting 1.3 doesn't work. This is what is meant with "the lower the version, the more platforms implement it."

Comment: sorry my typo error.  Why .NET Standard 1.0 is support .Net Framework 4.5.1 since .Net Framework 4.5.1 is implement .Net Standard 1.2.  Is it because backward compatible?

Comment: Yes, think of .net standard 1.2 as .net standard 1.0 plus some extras. So if .net framework 4.5.1 supports 1.2, it is also compatible with 1.0.